Rendering of action button in android is getting as ellipse for long text and it is rendering as scroll in ios for bot framework
`In Android teams the narrow down button with long description are visible in ellipse
enter image description here
But in IOS teams, it's allowing user to scroll the button
enter image description here
enter image description here
Here I want to apply scroll in action button in android ms-teams.
But while applying style it is overwritten by android rendering it own styling.
Options Tried but not working
1.Here I tried to apply inline styling as
**style: 'width: auto; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;' // Apply inline style here
   **
but it is still not working .
2.After applying external styling as
// Add viewport meta tag
card.content += <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">;
but it is still not working .
for this code:-
async Answer(step, options) {
let actions = [];
actions = options.map((option) => ({
  type: 'imBack',
  title: option,
  value: option,
  style: 'width: auto; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;' // Apply inline style here
}));
actions.push({
  type: 'imBack',
  title: i18nService.getSentence('none', step.context.locale),
  value: i18nService.getSentence('none', step.context.locale),
  style: 'width: auto; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;' // Apply inline style here
});
const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
  i18nService.getSentence('didyoumean', step.context.locale),
  i18nService.getSentence('pleasehelpnarrowsearch', step.context.locale),
  '',
  actions
);
// keeping it as cancelled because we are assuming that we are skipping narrow down by default. And if it is not skipped it will change its status according to the last step of dailog.
step.context.turnState.set(responseStatus,RESPONSE_TYPE.inprogress)`your text`;
step.context.turnState.set(responseFlags.isNarrowDown,true);
await step.context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] });
return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };

}
Can any one look into this and provide a feasible solution. `

You can try another options that are being offered by Adaptive Cards which offer more flexibility and customization options compared to hero cards. However using hero cards we did not observe such rendering of buttons.

Code for Hero card-
CardFactory.heroCard(
'BotFramework Hero Card',
CardFactory.images([''url]),
CardFactory.actions([
{
type: 'openUrl',
title: 'Get started with the functionalities of hero card and explore more',
value: 'https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/'
}
])
);
